# CSS not appearing with a certain id referenced

Tags: css

My goal is to make a new h2 that is a bit under the top of the site. Currently it says "NeonBLOX is a virtual playground.", yet it doesn't show up, I went into inspect element mode and I also noticed that it pops a bit out of the navigator. I realized, it seems to have no CSS connected to it yet I set it's id to "ib" and in the CSS file I referenced the ID and set the information to what I needed it to be, yet in element style there was no info, unlike the other things with IDs and classes referenced in CSS.

HTML:

```
<div id="ib">
    <h2 id="ib">NeonBLOX is a virtual playground.</h2>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#ib {
    color: black;
    position: relative;
    top: 200px;
    font-family: cursive, "Brush Script MT";
}
```

For some reason there is no css connected it says on the site. You can replicate it here: https://neonblox.000webhostapp.com/site/index.aspx (go into inspect mode to see the info you need)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Never duplicate IDs. Use a class instead.

Comment: I did what you said @miken32 and it didn't fix anything.

Comment: where do you want to place the h2 element? css is connected here

Comment: Then please update your question to include proper HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I don't mean to sound harsh in this comment! But I need to warn you, you're making it incredibly hard for yourself by position everything in relative positioning and coding all positions with pixels. This will for sure cause you headaches! Since I spotted multiple errors in your HTML I re-wrote what you want to achieve with explanations and some references.

```css
.container{
    max-width: 1200px; /*Sets the maximum width to 1200px, so the element can be smaller but can't exceed 1200px*/
    margin: 0 auto; /*centers the container element*/
}

img {
    width: 100%;
}

ul {
    display: flex; /*https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout*/
    gap: 20px; /*sets a bit of space between every element*/
    padding-left: 0; /*removes the default padding of 40 px on the left side*/
}

ul li {
    list-style-type: none; /*Removes the bullet points from the list-items*/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>

<!--Created a wrapper around all elements and give it a max-width of 1200px and set the margin to '0 auto' to place all content nicely in the middle of the screen.-->
<div class="container">
    <img src="https://neonblox.000webhostapp.com/images/earlysummerbanner.png" alt="">
    <!--Placed the navigation in a <nav> (navigation)-->
    <nav>
        <ul> <!--Placed your navigation in an Unordered-list as a menu is a 'list of links-->
            <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Neonblox</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Games</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <main>
        <!--Main is an element that indicated this is the place where the most important information is to be found-->
        <h1>NeonBLOX is a virtual playground.</h1>
    </main>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```